# Nested Form: How to set the User ID for child resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get my `User` to save to a `Rate`. I was able to get the `Location` to be saved to the Rate by removing the presence validation but after it's created it doesn't have the current user. How would I do this for my nested form?

**User.rb**

```
attr_accessible :email, :password
has_many :locations
has_many :rates
```

**Location.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :rates_attributes
belongs_to :user
has_many :rates
accepts_nested_attributes_for :rates, :reject_if => :all_blank
# Not sure if :all_blank works anyways as it - 
# still saves even when theirs no user_id, lol
```

**Rate.rb**

```
attr_accessible :amount, :location_id
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :user
validates_presence_of :amount
# Couldn't use these validations
# validates_presence_of :user_id 
# validates_presence_of :location_id
```

**LocationsController**

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
  @location.rates.build
end

def create
  @location = current_user.locations.build(params[:location])
  if @location.save.....
end
```

**locations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= nested_form_for @location do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Name *" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name  %>

  <%= f.link_to_add "Add Rate", :rates %>
  <%= f.fields_for :rates do |r| %>
    <%= r.text_field :amount %>
    <%= r.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Location" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great railscast on this topic; episodes 196 and 197.  Even better, Ryan wrote a gem https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.

The gem is super easy to implement.  If set up correctly the nested form grabs the parent object id on create automatically.

I don't notice anything in the code you have posted that looks wrong...what does your nested form look like in the view?

Comment: That's actually the where I learned how to do the nested form. My question though is how to get the `user_id`. The user isn't the parent, the location is.

Comment: I would probably do something like this in the nested form: <%= r.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user %>

Comment: But wouldn't that provide a security vulnerability? A hacker could pass different "user_id"s and manufacture messages that originate from different people, right?